# Close menu when click on li

Tags: javascript, jquery, menu

I making a single page website. When I open my menu and click on a li item, I want my menu to close.

For the moment it is working when I click back on the "menu-burger-wrapper" and I want to set the same thing when I click on items li.

There is my code:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

    $('#menu-burger-wrapper').click(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $this = $(this);
        if ($this.hasClass('is-opened')) {
            $this.addClass('is-closed').removeClass('is-opened');
        } else {
            $this.removeClass('is-closed').addClass('is-opened');
        }
    })
});
```

```html
<nav class="menu-base" id="menu-base">
    <ul class="menu-item">
        <a id="en-cours" class="work_menu link link--over">
            <li>works</li>
        </a>
        <a class="about_menu link link--over">
            <li>about</li>
        </a>
        <a class="link link--over">
            <li>contact</li>
        </a>
    </ul>
</nav>
<!-- Header -->
<div id="header">
    <!-- Menu -->
    <div id="menu-burger-wrapper">
        <div id="menu-burger">
            <div class="line line-1"></div>
            <div class="line line-2"></div>
            <div class="line line-3"></div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `toggleClass` to toggle class.

You can use `,` to separate the elements on which you want to bind event.

```
$('#menu-burger-wrapper, .menu-item').on('click', function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $(this).toggleClass('is-opened is-closed');
});

$('.menu-item').on('click', 'li', function() {
    $('#menu-burger-wrapper').trigger('click');
});
```

Demo: https://jsfiddle.net/tusharj/7c5nd7rj/1/

Comment: no it ' s not working :(  there is my jsfiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/Tibuakaw/7c5nd7rj/   for all the code

Answer (score 2):

Try this - just attach the click handler to the `li` elements.

```
var clickHandler = function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $this = $(this);
    if ($this.hasClass('is-opened')) {
        $this.addClass('is-closed').removeClass('is-opened');
    } else {
        $this.removeClass('is-closed').addClass('is-opened');
    }
};

//attaching the event to both, together.
$('#menu-burger-wrapper, ul.menu-item li').on('click', clickHandler);
```